# Android Studio GridLayout onTouch Event

Tags: android, background-color, grid-layout, ontouch

I want to create an App where I can change the color of the gestures of the GridLayout. 
[My_GridLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQmm9.png)
It works good with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (touchOn) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    touchOn = true;
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

With the xml code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/mygrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="8"
    android:rowCount="8"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3">
</GridLayout>
```

But I can only change the color of **one** gesture by touching the Grid. Is there a MotionEvent or something else which detect that I've touched a gesture and moved (without taking off the finger) to the next gesture? So that I can move over the Grid with my finger and the colors change one after another.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can detect gestures by implementing `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and `GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener` methods in your `MainActivity` and change the color for each gesture:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector; 

    // Called when the activity is first created. 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Instantiate the gesture detector with the
        // application context and an implementation of
        // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        // Set the gesture detector as the double tap
        // listener.
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { 
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString()); 
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString()); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll: " + e1.toString()+e2.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress: " + event.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can also track movement in touch events.

> You could have a movement-based gesture that is simply based on the
>   distance and/or direction the pointer traveled. But velocity often is
>   a determining factor in tracking a gesture's characteristics or even
>   deciding whether the gesture occurred. To make velocity calculation
>   easier, Android provides the VelocityTracker class and the
>   VelocityTrackerCompat class in the Support Library. VelocityTracker
>   helps you track the velocity of touch events. This is useful for
>   gestures in which velocity is part of the criteria for the gesture,
>   such as a fling.

Here is an example.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Velocity";
        ...
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker = null;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int index = event.getActionIndex();
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    // Retrieve a new VelocityTracker object to watch the velocity of a motion.
                    mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                }
                else {
                    // Reset the velocity tracker back to its initial state.
                    mVelocityTracker.clear();
                }
                // Add a user's movement to the tracker.
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                // When you want to determine the velocity, call 
                // computeCurrentVelocity(). Then call getXVelocity() 
                // and getYVelocity() to retrieve the velocity for each pointer ID. 
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                // Log velocity of pixels per second
                // Best practice to use VelocityTrackerCompat where possible.
                Log.d("", "X velocity: " + 
                        VelocityTrackerCompat.getXVelocity(mVelocityTracker, 
                        pointerId));
                Log.d("", "Y velocity: " + 
                        VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker,
                        pointerId));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // Return a VelocityTracker object back to be re-used by others.
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

See
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html:

> A "touch gesture" occurs when a user places one or more fingers on the touch screen, and your application interprets that pattern of
>   touches as a particular gesture. There are correspondingly two phases
>   to gesture detection:
>
> - Gathering data about touch events.
> - Interpreting the data to see if it meets the criteria for any of the gestures your app supports.

And https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html#velocity:

> A new onTouchEvent() is triggered with an ACTION_MOVE event whenever the current touch contact position, pressure, or size changes. As described in Detecting Common Gestures, all of these events are recorded in the MotionEvent parameter of onTouchEvent().

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried to use the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE but there is the same problem. Do I have to detect the velocity and calculate the next position? If yes, how is that possible?

Comment: @MFC_Starter check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html#velocity: